# Pre-loading images pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a game that currently has a frame rate issue. I do believe the problem is the rather large amount of images I am currently loading, so my question is: "Is there a way to preload images? So basically loading them before even being used?"

I don't know if this is possible, but it sounded good in my head. So basically nothing is being drawn to the screen, but the images are ready without any delay (or minimum).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's quite simple.

The easiest approach is to just create a `dict` that will function as a cache, and a method to load images from that cache:

```
image_cache = {}
def get_image(key):
  if not key in image_cache:
    image_cache[key] = pygame.image.load(key)
  return image_cache[key]
```

(If you need more functionality, maybe create a class for this).

Now, when you want to use an image, use the `get_image` function:

```
class Player(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.image = get_image('image1.png')
```

All images are now cached once loaded and reused if you want to use the same image again and again.

To preload all images at startup, you can either create a list of all images yourself

```
images = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']
```

or simple get the filenames of all images in a specific folder

```
import glob
images = glob.glob('*.png')
```

and load all images once:

```
# ensure all images are loaded
for image in images:
  get_image(image)
```

---

Also note that another common bottleneck is font rendering, which is quite expensive. You can cache font surfaces creating with `Font.render` with the same technique (using a simple `dict`).

Comment: while you load them, you might want to add a call to `.convert()` or `.convert_alpha()`, to speed up blitting. Pre loading would be the perfect place to do that. See http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert

Comment: Scratch the last comment. It no longer takes 20 seconds for my map to load and I am reaching well above what my standard frame rate is. I was initially getting something like 12 fps, but no I am getting above 60. Thankyou guys so much ^_^. This is also with 1000 images blitted to the screen (map is 100x100)